# How to print header with iTextSharp into .pdf document?

Tags: header, itext, pdf-generation

I converted [this java code](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-does-my-header-overlap-my-content) to C#, but I'm clearly missing something as the header is not present in my .pdf document.

Here's the converted code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage CreatePdf()
        {
            HeaderTable HeaderTable = new HeaderTable();
            //  step 1
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 20 + HeaderTable.getTableHeight(), 36);
            //  step 2
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            writer.CloseStream = false;

            writer.PageEvent = HeaderTable;
            //  step 3
            document.Open();
            //  step 4
            for (int i = 0; (i< 50); i++) {
                document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
            }

            document.NewPage();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
            document.NewPage();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
            //  step 5
            document.Close();

            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream)
                {
                    Headers =
                    {
                        ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf"),
                        ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                        {
                            FileName = "TEST.pdf"
                        }
                    }
                },
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
            };
        }

        public class HeaderTable : PdfPageEventHelper
        {
            protected PdfPTable table;

            protected float tableHeight;

            public HeaderTable()
            {
                table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.TotalWidth = 523;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                table.AddCell("Header row 1");
                table.AddCell("Header row 2");
                table.AddCell("Header row 3");
                tableHeight = table.TotalHeight;
            }

            public float getTableHeight()
            {
                return tableHeight;
            }

            public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
            {
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, (document.Top + ((document.TopMargin + tableHeight) / 2)), writer.DirectContent);
            }
        }
```

I'm sure I made a trivial mistake, but I didn't find it out yet. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
Instead of:

```
public class HeaderTable : PdfPageEventHelper
```

and

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
```

I should write:

```
public partial class HeaderTable : PdfPageEventHelper
```

and

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
```

Comment: `partial` should not be necessary (unless you have split the `HeaderTable` definition in your port), the important part is *overriding* using the *correct method name* (in iTextSharp the .Net convention of methods starting with uppercase letters are followed, in iText /Java the Java conventions  of methods starting with lowercase letters).